# OpenGL 4.1 Program Pipeline Uniforms

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

In OpenGL 4.1 the `separate_shader_objects` extension made it into core.

I know that I'm able to create/use a program pipeline object using `gl{Gen,Bind}ProgramPipeline()`. But how do I set Uniforms for this pipeline?

I've read of [`glProgramUniform()`](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glProgramUniform) but don't really understand it.

I think that `glProgramUniform` takes a (separable) program object.
When I now use a previously created program object as stage for a program pipeline and afterwards call `glProgramUniform` on this program object, will this affect the whole pipeline? Or do I have to call `glProgramUniform` for every single program object again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you implying that stages in your pipeline have uniforms with the same name? For example, the program associated with the vertex stage has a `uniform float time` and the program associated with the fragment stage has a `uniform float time`?

Considering the whole point of separable shaders is ***not*** linking stages together, there is no notion of shared uniforms. Each stage has its own discrete namespace.

#### This was addressed when the extension you mentioned was first proposed:

```
3.  Do different program objects currently used by different shader
    types share a single name space for uniforms?

    RESOLVED:  No, different program objects have their own separate
    name space for uniforms and each has locations specific to its
    unique program object.
```

That means you have to set uniforms for every program object in your pipeline, even if the stages share common names.